# syntax error in mysql during tringger definition

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to use a trigger defined as follows

```
-- the table
CREATE TABLE codici_ddt(
id_ordine VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
id_invoice VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ddt_numero INT(8) NOT NULL,
fatturazione DATE NOT NULL,
ddt VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(id_ordine) REFERENCES ordini_dal_web(id_ordine),
PRIMARY KEY(id_ordine)
);

--the_trigger

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER genera_numero_ddt BEFORE INSERT ON codici_ddt FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE ultimo_ddt INT(8);
  
  SELECT COALESCE(max(ddt_numero),1) INTO ultimo_ddt 
  FROM codici_ddt
  WHERE data_fatturazione >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(NEW.data_fatturazione)  ,1) 
    AND data_fatturazione <  MAKEDATE(YEAR(NEW.data_fatturazione)+1,1);

  SET NEW.ddt_numero = (ultimo_ddt+1)
  SET NEW.ddt = CONCAT(NEW.ddt_numero,'/',(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.data_fatturazione,'-',1),-2)),'c');
 END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

the message returned from mysql is

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'SET NEW.ddt =
> CONCAT(NEW.ddt_numero,'/',(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.data_fatt' at
> line 11

the CONCAT should be right, where is my error?

many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss ';' at the end of line.

```
  SET NEW.ddt_numero = (ultimo_ddt+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing semi-colon. Also you are referencing data_fatturazione instead of just fatturazione.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$



CREATE TRIGGER genera_numero_ddt BEFORE INSERT ON codici_ddt FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE ultimo_ddt INT(8);


SELECT COALESCE(max(ddt_numero),1) INTO ultimo_ddt    FROM codici_ddt

WHERE fatturazione >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(NEW.fatturazione)  ,1) 

AND fatturazione <  MAKEDATE(YEAR(NEW.fatturazione)+1,1);


SET NEW.ddt_numero = (ultimo_ddt+1);

SET NEW.ddt = CONCAT(NEW.ddt_numero,'/',(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.fatturazione,'-',1),-2)),'c');

END $$



DELIMITER ;
```